# SVN: How to get the first revision of a file?

Tags: svn, revision

When working with a subdirectory in a repository, how to find the revision when that specific directory has been added to the repository? By using "svn info http://.." I can find out when it was modified for the last time ("Last Changed Rev"), but I also need to find out the revision number of the commit when that directory (or file) was added for the first time (it's "first" revision).

I have been searching for that at the "SVN book", googling, but, obviously, I got no results.

Note: I need this for making a PHP script which downloads logs and stores them locally, just to make it clear and avoid "use tortoise/svnx/versions/you_name_it application" ;)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could use [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html), with a reverse revision range:

```
svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 <REPO_URL>
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it :)

Comment: Just did it. I'm new guy at the hood, I am still getting familiar :)

Comment: Only works if HEAD contains that file. If the file was deleted, this will fail

Comment: When you want first revision in given branch use option:  --stop-on-copy

Answer (score 2):

The last entry of

```
svn log http://...
```

Answer (score 2):

For someone trying to do this in pysvn:

```
def get_branch_creation_rev(url)
    import pysvn
    cl = pysvn.Client()
    return  pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number,
                           cl.log(url)[-1].data.get('revision').number)
```

Comment: also, if someone is looking to get the SVN author information aswell this is the command `cl.log(url)[-1].data.get('author')`